# Keep objects centered in place without moving

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to keep things centered in the browser without it stretching my divs and moving my videos..
when I stretch my browser it moves my images and objects around..
I want to keep objects inside the divs & have everything stay in place..
Is that possible using just css or do I have to use flexbox and java?
I've posted a image on whats going on and here is the coding for it all..
I'm sure it needs a little code cleaning..

```css
body {
background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3");
background-color: #ffffff;
background-position: top center;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
height:600px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-attachment:fixed;
z-index: 9999px;  
}

main {
background: #333333;
width:90%;
height:660px;
margin: 300px 0px 0px 100px;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 1;
}
  
.divl {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
float:left;
text-align:left;
width: 20%;
height: 96%;
margin:0px;
padding: 10px 20px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.divr {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
float:right;
text-align:right;
width: 20%;
height: 96%;
margin:0px;
padding: 10px 20px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.divc {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/800/nature/3") top center no-repeat, rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
text-align:center;
text-align:center;
width: 50%;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 96%;
margin:auto;
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}


.mnu { overflow:hidden; background-color:#F8F8F8; padding:2px; line-height:1.5em; cursor:pointer; }
.mnu a { display:block; cursor:pointer; width:100%; padding:0 2px 0 1px; margin:0; }
.mnu a:link { color:#000000; text-decoration:none; }
.mnu a:visited { color:#000000; text-decoration:none; }
.mnu a:hover { color:#000000; text-decoration:none; background-color:#F0F0F0; }
.mnu a:active { color:#000000; text-decoration:none; background-color:#EAEAEA; }
.fil { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
.ptr { cursor:pointer; }
.opr { filter:alpha(opacity=100); }
.trn { opacity:0; filter:alpha(opacity=0); }
.smf { -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }
.sol { background-color:blue; }
.bmk { border-style:dashed; border-width:0 0 1px 0; }
.ctr { position:relative; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:left; }
.ctt { text-align:center; }
.abs { position:absolute; }
.aut { overflow:auto; }
.hid { overflow:hidden; }
.scr { overflow:scroll; }
.vis { overflow:visible; }
.inv { visibility:hidden; }
.cms { }
.col { background-color:transparent; clear:left; float:left; }
.cor { background-color:transparent; clear:right; float:right; }
.required { }
.nvo { }
.bgremove { background-image:none; }

.nml { }
.hd1,h1 { font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-style:italic; font-size:18px; text-align:center; }
.hd2,h2 { font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-style:italic; font-size:15px; }
.hd3,h3 { font-weight:bold; }
.mnus { padding:0px; border-width:2px; border-style:outset; background-color:#CEE5F2; text-align:center; }
.mnus a:hover { color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000080; }
.mnus a:active { color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#0000CC; }
.pnl { border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#8DC7EB; background-color:#CEE5F2; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="created" content="Tue, 19 Feb 2019 02:15:52 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
    
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

<main>
  <div class="divl">Music<br> Here Is A List Of Music</div>
  <div class="divr">Producers<br> Here Is A List Of Producers</div>
  <div class="divc">Videos<br><div id="lays581qvlpb">
<div id="pict581wjphg" class="hid abs" style="left:1199px; top:300px; width:100px; height:100px;"
 onclick="document.getElementById('lays585jmqnb').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('lays585mobib').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('lays585cwgno').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('lays585tvnws').style.visibility='hidden';">
<img id="pict581wjphgi" class="fil smf" src="img-1.png" alt="">
</div>
<div id="pict581nqvmq" class="hid abs" style="left:1199px; top:399px; width:100px; height:100px;"
 onclick="document.getElementById('lays585jmqnb').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('lays585mobib').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('lays585cwgno').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('lays585tvnws').style.visibility='hidden';">
<img id="pict581nqvmqi" class="fil smf" src="img-2.png" alt="">
</div>
<div id="pict583yfwki" class="hid abs" style="left:1199px; top:498px; width:100px; height:100px;"
 onclick="document.getElementById('lays585jmqnb').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('lays585mobib').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('lays585cwgno').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('lays585tvnws').style.visibility='hidden';">
<img id="pict583yfwkii" class="fil smf" src="img-1.png" alt="">
</div>
<div id="pict583fdwaz" class="hid abs" style="left:1199px; top:597px; width:100px; height:100px;"
 onclick="document.getElementById('lays585jmqnb').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('lays585mobib').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('lays585cwgno').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('lays585tvnws').style.visibility='visible';">
<img id="pict583fdwazi" class="fil smf" src="img-2.png" alt="">
</div>
</div>
<div id="lays585jmqnb">
<div id="ytub586qorjf" class="hid abs" style="left:600px; top:300px; width:600px; height:397px; border-width:1px;
 border-style:solid; border-color:#808080;" border="0">
 <iframe style="width:100%; height:100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Lzkbf9wrMcQ?hd=1
 " frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
<div id="lays585mobib" style="visibility:hidden">
<div id="ytub586vzlff" class="hid abs" style="left:600px; top:300px; width:600px; height:397px; border-width:1px;
 border-style:solid; border-color:#808080;" border="0">
 <iframe style="width:100%; height:100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9SI2xE0ixws?hd=1
 " frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
<div id="lays585cwgno" style="visibility:hidden">
<div id="ytub587seayk" class="hid abs" style="left:600px; top:300px; width:600px; height:397px; border-width:1px;
 border-style:solid; border-color:#808080;" border="0">
 <iframe style="width:100%; height:100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/U5LgnJI1FfI?hd=1
 " frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
<div id="lays585tvnws" style="visibility:hidden">
<div id="ytub587wsjnq" class="hid abs" style="left:600px; top:300px; width:600px; height:397px; border-width:1px;
 border-style:solid; border-color:#808080;" border="0">
 <iframe style="width:100%; height:100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/C9jH6mK_wUg?hd=1
 " frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div></div>
  </main>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give a wrapping block element a width and `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: How do I go about doing that tho? I'm new to this and slowly learning. Also for some reason it made my videos off center.. how would i fit the videos in the center of the middle div?

Comment: In other words, are you trying to have a fixed layout? Most people these days _want_ their pages to transform (aka shift around) as you change viewport size... it's called responsive design. Optimizing how it changes is the name of the game, and yes you'd probably use flexbox to do so. You usually would only engage Javascript (not Java) as a last resort, for things you cannot achieve with CSS.

Comment: Use a div directly inside the body. Give the div a class called main or something, then use do like `.main{ width:980px; margin:0 auto;}`.

Comment: I will have a fixed background and everything else will scroll.. For now i have the <main></main> div set to a small height so it don't scroll.. but i want my video and content to stay inside the divs i have.. forsome reason my youtube videos move whenever i move my browser size.. If it's the new thing how do I go about centering everything so it dont move out of place..

Comment: I heard using percentages instead of pixels is why it dont work right but for some reason no matter what i try it doesnt work right and my videos are still out of place..